# How do I gather statistics from ESSBASE?

Tags: oracle, hyperion, essbase

I would like to gather some statistics about the usage of several cubes with Hyperion ESSBASE.
I've found [that](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESBTR/maxl_pstats_tables.html) from the official documentation but doesn't seem what I need.

What I would like to achieve is to know how many times a dimension has been queried, in which cube, which dimensions are often used together and so on.
Is there any tool or maxl instruction for that pourpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know such a tool. There is an option called query tracking which is used internal by essbase for aggregation but i dont know a way do display this information.

Sorry but i am afraid there is no solution for your problem.

Greets
Kevin